Trying to set up mock sockets with Jest in React
I'm trying to set up mocking of sockets in frontend with the help of Jest to unit test. I keep getting errors.
const socket = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? new MockSocket() : io(`${REACT_APP_FEEDER_SOCKET_URL}`, {
  path: "/socket.io",
  transports: ["websocket"],
  query: {
    token: localStorage.getItem('induction_token') 
  }
});

Here is my Jest implementation:
import SocketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import MockSocket from '../mocks/socket.io-client'
import { __esModule } from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

jest.mock('socket.io-client', () => {
    return {
      __esModule: true,
      default: MockSocket
    };
  });

describe('Socket testing', () => {
    it('Should listen to "random_status_direct" event and handle data', () => {

        const myModule = require('../redux/services/socket').default;

        const eventData = {
            feedlane_id: "feeder_1",
            station: "station-1",
            feedlane_status: false,
            connected_peripherals: ["scanner-1"],
            floor_status: true,
            dashboard_status: true,
            status: false
        };

        myModule.mockSocket.emit("random_status_direct", eventData);

        expect(myModule.handleFeedlaneStatus).toHaveBeenCalledWith(eventData);
    });
});

Here is my mock socket implementation:
class MockSocket {
    constructor() {
        this.listeners = {}
    }

    on(event, callback) {
        if (!this.listeners[event]) {
            this.listeners[event] = [];
        }
        this.listeners[event].push(callback);
    }

    emit(event,data) {
        if (this.listeners[event]) {
            this.listeners[event].forEach(callback => {
                callback(data);
            });
        }
    }
}

module.exports = {
    connect: () => new MockSocket()
};

Is this the right way to mock sockets when developing on frontend? I mocked all API data through mock service workers and I want to mock socket data; since the application replies heavily on sockets, mocking API data did not give much help. The error I am getting is this:
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')

       6 |     return {
       7 |       __esModule: true,
    >  8 |       default: MockSocket
         |                ^
       9 |     };
      10 |   });
      11 |

      at src/tests/mySocketTest.test.js:8:16
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/mySocketTest.test.js:1:1)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)

I would like to know different ways to mock sockets also if anyone has any idea.
